# How to send multiple responses for a request in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I have a request to Laravel (PHP) in which user uploads 100 files. I have to process these files using PHP which would take about 5 seconds for each file. After processing each file I have to send a response back to user informing that the process is complete for that file. How I can do this?
First I made a system, to make 100 parallel axios requests but that spawns several php-fpm processes which almost stops the server. Please help.

Comment: Do you already have an active queuing system in place that you could use to process the files? Because in my opinion, this task with a potential, sequential duration of 500s asks for an asynchronous background execution with asynchronous status updates to the frontend (via broadcasting or polling).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Currently since these requests are handled paralllely the task usually completes in about 30 seconds from user's point of view. But I guess it is too many PHP processes for server. Do you suggest using websockets to inform the progress to user and run a single PHP process in the background?

Answer (score -1):

- I think you can use if...else here and return array in json response.
  like

  $data['file1']='succcess';

  $data['file2'] = 'success';

  and so on like this

May be this answer directs you.
Thanks.

Comment: But I want to send that response in parts, let's say for 100 files there will be 100 repsonses of completion. How can I send a response after every file has been processed?

Comment: You can use the one varriable and than increment varriable in foreach loop and use array varriable concate with increment value so you can get response base on your files